# VueJS Routing/Navigation issues

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, netlify

Having trouble using VueJS (first time using it)

- I have 90% of my page template in the index.html file in doc root
- I have 3 components (each contains the main content body for each 'page')

My router:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  hash: false,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/gallery',
      name: 'Gallery',
      component: Gallery
    },
    {
      path: '/contact',
      name: 'Contact',
      component: Contact
    }
  ]
})
```

I can't get `<router-link :to="{ name: 'Gallery' }">Gallery</router-link>` to work - my site doesn't render them as anchor tags in my index.html (I'm probably not understanding how/where Vue can be used there) - so I'm using a standard link e.g. `<a class="nav-link" href="/gallery">Gallery</a>`

The problem:

While all of this code works fine on my local machine, it doesn't work anywhere that I upload my code to (I would like to have it working on Netlify). Netlify and other sites overwrite my attempts to remove the hash, so my links then link to e.g.

`https://examplesite.com/#/ => https://examplesite.com/gallery#/`

Comment: You shouldn't need to fall-back to an `<a>` tag. Try `<router-link to="/gallery">`?

Comment: @puddi Unfortunately it doesn't get rendered as an anchor tag, it gets outputted to the page as is and therefore is not even displayed on the page

Comment: I would double-check that your Vue application is properly `use`ing/including the router library, then, because it sounds like vue-router isn't being picked up properly.

Comment: @puddi I suspect that the `index.html` in the document root is outside the scope of the router - using `<router-link>` in individual components works fine

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`hash` is not a `Router` option. Try removing this.
To use history mode on Netlify, you have to add a `_redirects` file to your `public` directory.
Add this to the file:

`/*    /  200`
This will make sure that all paths are handled by the `vue-router`

Comment: Hi James - I didn't have a `public` directory, however I have added this `_redirects` file to my `dist` folder and now the site appears to work on Netlify, thanks :)

Comment: @Matadeleo when you add the public forlder with the _redirects, i'll be created every time you Build the project. Otherwise you could forget to add the _redirects file when build i or there could be any issue with the deployment if you forget this step

Comment: This one reaaally worked for my Vue.js / Quasar App! Great!